# Why is this small javascript not working?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple instances of a div with an id of "myDiv" on a page. I want to replace the contents of these divs. When I use this javascript:

```
function replaceContent(id, content) {
    var container = document.getElementById(id);
    container.innerHTML = content;
}

replaceContent('myDiv', 'hello there');


<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

It only replaces the content inside one of those divs and not all of them. If I use the .html() function of jquery instead, it replaces the contents of all divs. Is there any way I can get the above js to work in the same way?

Comment: "multiple instances of a div with an id of `myDiv`" Well that's your problem right there! `id` should be unique. Use `class` if you want something that's non-unique

Answer (score 7, accepted):

id values must be unique - you can't have more than one id with the same name and update all of them.

Answer (score 1):

> I have multiple instances of a div with an id of "myDiv" on a page.

This is where you're doing it wrong. You **cannot** assign an ID to multiple elements on a page - it has to be unique.

> It only replaces the content inside one of those divs and not all of them.

This happens because `getElementById()` returns only the first-matched element in case multiple such elements are matched.

---

To solve this, assign a *class* instead of an *ID* to the divs you want to target, and if you can use jQuery, use this instead (assuming `class="myDiv"`):

```
function replaceContent(className, content) {
    $('div.' + className).html(content);
}

// This appends className so the selector becomes $('div.myDiv')
replaceContent('myDiv', 'hello there');
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs have to be unique. You can use the same class name for all divs and then use a css selector.

```
<div id="div1" class="mydivs">blah</div>
<div id="div2" class="mydivs">blah123</div>
```

For e.g. In JQuery, you could do:

```
$('.mydivs').html("whatever");
```

Comment: In my opinion, Jquery's too good. It takes the fun out of programming.